# Validation rule exempting user and profile

Tags: validation

I have a address object, where I have to give a validation rule for one field name sequence ID

**Requirement is** : when sequence ID is assigned no user cannot edit other fields except one user integration_user@sf.com and 3 profile(system admin, system admin1, system admin2)

I wrote the rule but when I exempt those user and profile, they are not exempting means they cannot even edit other fields along with sequence ID.

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Sequence_ID__c)),
    $User.Username <> 'integration_user@sf.com',
    OR(
       NOT( $Profile.Name = "system admin1"),
       NOT( $Profile.Name = "system admin2"),
       NOT( $Profile.Name = "system admin3")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> no user cannot edit other fields except 
>   one user integration_user@sf.com 
>   **and** 
>   3 profile(system admin, system admin1, system admin2)

So, between user and profile comparison, you need to put AND instead of OR

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Sequence_ID__c)),
    $User.Username <> 'integration_user@sf.com',
    NOT( $Profile.Name = "system admin1"),
    NOT( $Profile.Name = "system admin2"),
    NOT( $Profile.Name = "system admin3")
)
```

You can use like this way too

```
NOT(ISBLANK(Sequence_ID__c) 
&& ($User.Username <> 'integration_user@sf.com' 
    && ($Profile.Name <> "system admin1" 
    && $Profile.Name <> "system admin2"
    && $Profile.Name <> "system admin3"
    )
)
```

Comment: You can just remove that second `AND`. Or the parens wrapping the `$Profile` clauses in your second approach. Redundant.

Comment: Thank you all, I have just figure it out like this :                                            
AND( 
NOT(ISBLANK(Sequence_ID__c)), 
NOT(OR( 
$User.Username <> 'integration_user@sf.com', 
$Profile.Name = "system admin1", 
$Profile.Name = "system admin2", 
$Profile.Name = "system admin3"
) 
) 
)

Comment: @SFlast if my answer solves your issue then accept this, so that others may find this useful.